# Add an onclick attribute to a link tag using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have an internal website that has a link with NO `onClick` attribute present.

I want to add an `onclick` attribute with a function as the value, like so:

```
onClick="LinkTracker();return true"
```

So that I get a call to the function, but the link click is still followed by the browser.

I tried:

```
item.onclick=Function("LinkTracker();return true");
```

I also tried just a simple function with no return info, and that function was never called either.

When I inspect the link element with Firebug, I do not see the `onclick` attribute set.
I DO see the `href` value (which I changed) properly updated.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.onclick=function(){LinkTracker();return true;}
```

try that.

[test case](http://jsfiddle.net/buR5g/1)